# Toggle Class Only in One Parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, parent

I have the code below that changes the class of a selection so that the user can only select one out of all the options. When there's one set of products per page, it's easily done but when I introduce two sets or more, the users can only select one between multiple groups.

I need a way to ensure that the toggling of the class only applies within the parent div of each button.

I.e. a user can select button 1 and button 3 but not button 1 and 2 or button 3 and 4

**Updated**

Only the product sets can have IDs

Products themselves as well as buttons can't have individual IDs

```js
var box = $(".Button");
box.click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("Green");
  box.not(this).removeClass("Green");
});
```

```css
.Label {
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 5%;
  font-size: 16px;
  float: center;
  position: relative;
}

.Button {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  background: #0096db;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  position: static;
  float: left;
  min-width: 25%;
  max-width: 40%;
}

.Button.Green {
  background: #64B448;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  position: static;
  float: left;
  min-width: 25%;
  max-width: 40%;
}

.productset1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 2fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(10px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 5px;
}
.productset2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 2fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(10px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
  <span>Product Set 1</span>
</h1>

<div class="productset1">
  <div class="product">
  <span class="Button">
  <span class="Label">Button 1</span>
  </span>
  </div>
    <div class="product">
  <span class="Button">
  <span class="Label">Button 2</span>
  </span>
  </div>
    <div class="product">
  <span class="Button">
  <span class="Label">Button 3</span>
  </span>
  </div>
    <div class="product">
  <span class="Button">
  <span class="Label">Button 4</span>
  </span>
  </div>
</div>


<h1>
  <span>Product Set 2</span>
</h1>

<div class="productset2">
  <div class="product">
  <span class="Button">
  <span class="Label">Button 5</span>
  </span>
  </div>
    <div class="product">
  <span class="Button">
  <span class="Label">Button 6</span>
  </span>
  </div>
    <div class="product">
  <span class="Button">
  <span class="Label">Button 7</span>
  </span>
  </div>
      <div class="product">
  <span class="Button">
  <span class="Label">Button 8</span>
  </span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: If you use radio inputs, with button-like styling, you get this behaviour for free; so why use `<button>` elements?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @Ivan I tried .parent('.productset1') without success

Comment: @DavidThomas This is a simplified version of what my HTML is - the buttons contain more information so it's not possible to use radio inputs.

Comment: @AliSyme - You might want to put together a separate question about how you can do this with radio inputs and labels, showing the complex version of your buttons; it's extremely likely you can do this with radio inputs and labels, no matter how complex the buttons are. That said, it may make the markup complex enough that it's not worth doing that way.

Comment: While we do ask for "*[mcve]*" - with an emphasis on the 'minimal' - it's probably worth showing enough information for your `<button>` elements that we can see what you're working with. If only to avoid edge-cases from insufficient information, and context about which we don't know.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'll update with fuller information.

Comment: @DavidThomas I'll update (y)

Comment: @AliSyme - Not **this** question, this question has been answered. A *different* question (if you want to pursue an HTML+CSS-only solution). Editing this question will probably result in a rollback, since questions shouldn't be moving targets.

Comment: (The topic areas are also different. This question is about doing something in JavaScript with the jQuery API only within an element and its descendants; that question is about using HTML and CSS to create the UI you want.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder honestly I get a lot of 'why are you doing this?' questions and comments and not a lot of helpful information here. A lot of people comment with the best of intentions I'm sure but the tone is very sarky.

Comment: @AliSyme - Sometimes it is, yeah, though I don't think David's tone was. :-) As you say, oftentimes it's well-meaning -- sometimes well-meaning and polite, sometimes well-meaning and a bit sarky, but sometimes...just sarky. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only look for other buttons within the parent:

```
var box = $(".Button");
box.click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.toggleClass("Green");
  $this.parent().find(".Button").not(this).removeClass("Green");
});
```

Example:

```js
var box = $(".Button");
box.click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.toggleClass("Green");
  $this.parent().find(".Button").not(this).removeClass("Green");
});
```

```css
.Button {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  background: #0096db;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  position: static;
  float: right;
  min-width: 25%;
  max-width: 40%;
}

.Button.Green {
  background: #64B448;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  position: static;
  float: right;
  min-width: 25%;
  max-width: 40%;
}

.productset1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 2fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(10px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 5px;
}
.productset2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 2fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(10px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Product Set 1</h1>

<div class="productset1">
<span class="Button">Button 1</span>
<span class="Button">Button 2</span>
</div>

<h1>Product Set 2</h1>

<div class="productset2">
<span class="Button">Button 3</span>
<span class="Button">Button 4</span>
</div>
```

---

Or, as [David Thomas pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50784674/toggle-class-only-in-one-parent/50784758#comment88575856_50784674), get it without script with radio inputs:

Example:

```css
.Button {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  background: #0096db;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  position: static;
  float: right;
  min-width: 25%;
  max-width: 40%;
}

input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + .Button {
  background: #64B448;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  position: static;
  float: right;
  min-width: 25%;
  max-width: 40%;
}

.productset1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 2fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(10px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 5px;
}
.productset2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 2fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(10px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Product Set 1</h1>

<div class="productset1">
<input id="btn1" type="radio" name="set1">
<label for="btn1" class="Button">Button 1</label>
<input id="btn2" type="radio" name="set1">
<label for="btn2" class="Button">Button 2</label>
</div>

<h1>Product Set 2</h1>

<div class="productset2">
<input id="btn3" type="radio" name="set2">
<label for="btn3" class="Button">Button 3</label>
<input id="btn4" type="radio" name="set2">
<label for="btn4" class="Button">Button 4</label>
</div>
```

...but it does increase the complexity of the markup. :-)

Comment: Will definitely be trying this out as well as the radio input option if it's possible!

Answer (score 1):

As long as your DOM structure stays simple, you can use jQuery's `siblings()` function:

```
var box = $(".Button");
box.click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass("Green");
   $(this).siblings(".Button").removeClass("Green");
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/siblings/